# Not sure where my argument breaks down: Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a countable set. Prove that $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is uncountable.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$\textit{Proof.}$ Since A is countable, we know it has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$, or $\mid A \mid = \mid \mathbb{N} \mid$. Additionally, since $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$, it is enough to prove that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, an uncountable set. We will use the Schroeder - Bernstein Theorem:
$f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x$
$g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, $g(x) = \frac{1}{e^{x} + 2}$
As we have defined two injections, by the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\mid \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N} \mid = \mid \mathbb{R} \mid$, so $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is uncountable. Thus, $R \setminus A$ is uncountable. $\square$

Comment: what's the issue? looks fine to me

Comment: A countable set could have finite cardinality as well, so saying $|A|=|\Bbb{N}|$ is not entirely correct.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you cannot replace $A$ by $\mathbb N$ just because both these sets are countable. For example the set of even numbers is countable and its complement in the set of natural numbers is countable but if you replace it by the set of natural numbers, the complement becomes empty. So  your replacement could change the cardinality of the complement.

Comment: @AnuragA there are different definitions for the term "countable". Some authors use "countable" to mean $|A| = |\Bbb{N}|$, while some authors mean $|A| \leq |\Bbb{N}|$

Comment: @peek-a-boo: However, that first usage should be discouraged and replaced by *countably infinite*.

Comment: @JCAA In this particular case he can do the replace because this not chage the cardinality of the complement of entire set. In your example this happens because the entire set has the same cardinality of the set that you want to sustrac.

Comment: The question of whether it changes the cardinality is exactly the question asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the complement was countable then the set of reals would be the union of two countable sets, hence countable, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, this seems the more natural and simpler way to prove it!